# Add Attribute to ElementNode created by TSQL FOR XML Path

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to match some XML output in a SQL Server 2008 TSQL query.  The XML I am matching can return Lists of items.  The lists are identified by attribute name - not the node name.

The XML Path functions will return a wrapper node but I can't find a way to add any attributes to that node.  In my case they will be hard coded values based on the table name I am running they select against.

I have the 'x' as 'x' in there to keep the two lists separated.  In my actual data that is not a problem as these are in different nodes.  The problem is just how to get attributes added to the "List" node.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle page for the example below](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/395fa/3):

Sample Schema

```
create table Table1 (Value varchar(50)); 
create table Table2 (Value varchar(50)); 

insert Table1 values
('A'), ('B'), ('C');

insert Table2 values
('X'), ('Y'), ('Z');
```

Sample Select

```
select 
(
 select Value as '@I'
 from Table1
 for XML PATH('L'), TYPE
) as List,
'x' as 'x', -- needed to keep the Lists apart.
(
 select Value as '@I'
 from Table2
 for XML PATH('L'), TYPE
) as List

for XML PATH
```

Actual Output

```
<row>
  <List>
    <L I="A"/>
    <L I="B"/>
    <L I="C"/>
  </List>

  <x>x</x>

  <List>
    <L I="X"/>
    <L I="Y"/>
    <L I="Z"/>
  </List>
</row>
```

Desired Output: (Adding the "Name" attribute to the list wrapper.)

```
<row>
  <List Name='Table1'>  <!-- Added Attribute "Name" here -->
    <L I="A"/>
    <L I="B"/>
    <L I="C"/>
  </List>

  <x>x</x>

  <List Name='Table2'>  <!-- Added Attribute "Name" here -->
    <L I="X"/>
    <L I="Y"/>
    <L I="Z"/>
  </List>
</row>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to give the correct output. An extra level of `XML PATH` nesting is required to get the attribute onto the `List` node:

```
SELECT
(SELECT 'Table1' AS '@name',
  (SELECT Value AS '@I'
   FROM Table1
   FOR XML PATH ('L'))
 FOR XML PATH('List'), TYPE)
,'x' AS'x'
,( SELECT 'Table2' AS '@name',
  (SELECT Value AS '@I'
   FROM Table2
   FOR XML PATH ('L'))
 FOR XML PATH('List'), TYPE
)

FOR XML PATH;
```